Fiori Launchpad set different theme based on user
I have a requirement where we have created two launchpad themes.
We are able to launch the fiori launchpad in those two separate themes by adding theme parameter in the launchpad url.
However we dont need this approach instead both the themes should get defaulted for two different user groups
Is there any way?
Any help is much appreciated
Thank You
we have one custom theme already defaulted in tcode nwb_cfg_cust
hiwever with a 2nd new theme both the themes should get defaulted .
